# Displaying the list of users that can access a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to display the list of users that have access to a table (MySQL) in my VB application. I want to display this in a listbox.

```
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & serverTB.Text & ";" & "user id=" & userTB.Text & ";" & _
            "password=" & pwdTB.Text & ";" & "database=" & databaseTB.Text
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(MysqlConn.ConnectionString)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT USER FROM users"

        Dim list = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        For Each user In list
            userListCBX.Items.Add(user)
        Next
```

I get **Unknown column 'USER' in 'field list'**. I want the users from database test, table users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the reader to next record by calling `Read()` after getting information from current record has been done :

```
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    serListCBX.Items.Add(reader(0))
End While
```

See example usage of `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: Worked! I didn't realize MySQL and MSSQL were the same (or similar). I've just started playing around with SQL.

One more question: How would I get the users of one table? It's listing users globally.

Comment: Put some kind of `WHERE` clause to the SQL query according to you requirement : `SELECT USER FROM users WHERE table = 'something'` ?

Comment: Hmmm... struggling here. I have SELECT USER FROM mysql.user; I've tried to modify it to SELECT USER FROM mysql.user.test WHERE table = 'users' but that didn't work. I get a syntax error.

Comment: Your new question isn't clear and not worth to be a new question as posted, all it does is referring this question. I meant, let the new question focused on finding the correct MySQL query syntax for your purpose. Please refine it, state what you need the query to return, and what you have achieved so far, like you already have `SELECT USER FROM mysql.user.test` and don't know how to improve this query to return users that can access specific table...

Comment: BTW, what is `mysql.user.test` in your sample? That is strange for a name of table...